# Web Design - CSS sticky footer overlapping JQUERY content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know there are lots of questions asked about CSS Sticky Footers.

My issue is that my sticky footer is working completely fine the way I want it to-- except on my Portfolio page where I am using JQuery to display my content.

The Footer is overlapping the descriptions in my JQuery plug-in in smaller screen resolutions. I tried adding a min-height for the plug-in but it did not work.

www.toddmilliken.com/portfolio.html

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

-Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style of your footer is the following:

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
    height: 50px;
    clear: both;
    background: #332532;
}
```

The element overlaps the content above, because the `margin-top` is set to `-50px`. Try setting it to `0` and the problem will be solved ;)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest fix I can suggest is to put non semantic element with height of 50px at the end of your #wrap container. The code should be similar to:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <EXISTING CONTENT HERE>
  <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```